# Bad configuration options

Tags: parse-server

I am trying to connect my parse server instance but I keep getting this error on my terminal even though I have not changed the lines below

```
/Users/candilikoglu/.ssh/config: line 82: Bad configuration option: usepam
/Users/candilikoglu/.ssh/config: line 106: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/Users/candilikoglu/.ssh/config: line 112: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/Users/candilikoglu/.ssh/config: terminating, 4 bad configuration options
Cans-MacBook-Pro:desktop candilikoglu$
```

Comment: What is the command that you are using and is generating this error?

Comment: `code` chmod 400 firstServer.pem"                                                                                 `code` ssh -i "domainKey" admin@ec2-3-143-237-56.us-east- 
                                                                              2.compute.amazonaws.com                @DaviMacêdo

Comment: This command has nothing to do with Parse Server.